# PyCharm Edu: How to fix "solution can't be loaded"?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been taking the `Introduction to Python` course on PyCharm Edu. It has been going well for most of the time, except there's this weird bug that I can't seem to fix. I messed up on one of the tasks, and now whenever I try to check the task, it says:

> Solution can't be loaded. Reset task to solve it again.

[image: "Solution can't be loaded. Reset task to solve it again."]

Now, [this button right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceG6q.png) is supposed to reset the task. It does, however, even after clicking it, I still get the same error. This has happened on two tasks so far: the Undefined variable task and the return keyword task.

[image: this button right here]

I am extremely confused on why this is happening. If someone could help me fix this I would be very grateful! Thank you for reading.

**EDIT:** This is the code under the Undefined variable task:

```
variable = 1
print(other_variable)
```

This is also what `answer.py` for this task contains as well.

Comment: could you show the code under the Undefined variable task ?

Comment: Sure. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open in editor ***.idea/study_project.xml*** file in project *Introduction to Python* and find task you which show this message (for ex. return_in.py) and delete this code:

```
<entry key="__pycache__">
<value>
  <TaskFile>
    <option name="answerPlaceholders">
      <list />
    </option>
    <option name="highlightErrors" value="false" />
    <option name="trackChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="trackLengths" value="true" />
    <option name="userCreated" value="true" />
    <option name="name" value="__pycache__" />
    <option name="text" />
  </TaskFile>
</value>  
</entry>

<entry key="string_multiplication_windows">
<value>
  <TaskFile>
    <option name="answerPlaceholders">
      <list />
    </option>
    <option name="highlightErrors" value="false" />
    <option name="trackChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="trackLengths" value="true" />
    <option name="userCreated" value="true" />
    <option name="name" value="string_multiplication_windows" />
    <option name="text" />
  </TaskFile>
</value>
```